# Iterate through a list of data and add it to nested models

Tags: c#

I have to go through files with metadata and I am unhappy with the iteration and how I have build it due to the fact, that I have a modeltree with lists. So basically I iterate through `filesOfFolder` and pick each file and then I am adding the metadata. In the `else` I am checking, if the fileName has the same beginning then the fileNameBefore, because then it is a child of the last file, and it needs a different `documentOrderNumber`.

The modeltree is like and it cannot get changed:

```
Mainmodel
   Documents (public MainDocumentModel[] and AttDocumentModel[])
       MainDocumentModel
           FileContent
       AttDocumentModel
           FileContent
```

So as of this tree I did it so and I am totally unhappy with that:

```csharp
string fileNameBefore = "";
model.Documentlist = new Documents
{
    Attdocument = new AttDocumentModel[filesOfFolder.Count() + 1]
};
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;

string mainPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + model.DocId + "/");
string directoryAttPath = mainPath + "Att/";
Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryAttPath);

foreach (var file in filesOfFolder)
{
    if (file.f_name.Contains("Maindocument") || file.f_name.Contains("Wrapdocument"))
    {
        FileContent fContent = new FileContent();
        fContent.FileType = "PDF";
        fContent.FileName = "Maindocument.pdf";

        MainDocumentModel mainDoc = new MainDocumentModel();
        mainDoc.MainDoc = new List<FileContent>();
        mainDoc.Message = "";
        mainDoc.Status = true;
        mainDoc.MainDoc.Add(fContent);

        model.Documentlist.Maindocument = new MainDocumentModel[1];
        model.Documentlist.Maindocument[0] = mainDoc;
        string mainDocumentPath = mainPath + fContent.FileName;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(mainDocumentPath, file.f_file);
    }
    else
    {
        if (!(fileNameBefore.Split(' ')[0] == file.f_name.Split(' ')[0]))
        {
            j = 0;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
        }
        FileContent attachment = new FileContent();
        string documentOrderNumber = GenerateOrderNumberForRis(i, j, fileNameBefore);
        attachment.FileName = documentOrderNumber + ".pdf";
        attachment.FileType = "PDF";

        AttDocumentModel attDoc = new AttDocumentModel();
        attDoc.AttDoc = new List<FileContent>();
        attDoc.Message = "";
        attDoc.Status = true;
        attDoc.ShowName = file.f_subject;
        attDoc.AttDoc.Add(attachment);

        model.Documentlist.Attdocument[k] = attDoc;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(directoryAttPath + documentOrderNumber + ".pdf", file.f_file);
        k++;
        fileNameBefore = file.f_name;
    }
}
```

Here are the models:

```csharp
public class MainModel
{
    ....
    [XmlIgnore]
    public MainDocumentModel Maindocument { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public AttDocumentModel Attdocument { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "documentlist")]
    public Documents Documentlist  { get; set; }
}


[XmlRoot(elementName: "maindocument")]
public class MainDocumentModel
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public String Message { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Boolean Status { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("content")]
    public List<FileContent> MainDoc { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(elementName: "attacheddocument")]
public class AttDocumentModel
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public String Message { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Boolean Status { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("showname")]
    public string ShowName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("content")]
    public List<FileContent> AttDoc { get; set; }
}

public class FileContent
{
    [XmlElement("dataformat")]
    public string FileType { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("uri")]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: fileNameBefore is never modified and will always be ""... Please add the code and class of variables.

Comment: Added it @MartinVerjans, forgot the last line `fileNameBefore = file.f_name;`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the following statement: "I am totally unhappy with that"?

Answer (score 1):

Some quick remarks.

- Don't pointlessly abbreviate: `fContent` isn't a clear name, for instance.
- `i`, `j` and `k` are okay names for variables in a `for`-loop, but here they really should have meaningful names.
- Avoid adding words like "list" to names of collections. Especially when `Documentlist` isn't a collection, but the oddly named `Documents`. A class with a plural name? Which is then initialized by setting the badly named property `Attdocument`?
- I'm assuming that you cannot change the property name `f_name`?
- Are you certain that `.Contains("Maindocument")` will always work? Or should it be case insensitive?
- In several places you seem to use string concatenation to create directory paths. Avoid this and instead use `Path.Combine()`.
- When you construct the MainDocumentModel, try to keep it succinct. (I have omitted `Message = ""` since IMHO it seems superfluous: why not simply leave it `null`?) Same for `AttDocumentModel` in the `else`, BTW.

  ```
    var mainDocumentModel = new MainDocumentModel
    {
        Status = true,
        MainDoc = new List<FileContent>{ fContent }
    };
  ```
- I have trouble figuring out what `if (!(fileNameBefore.Split(' ')[0] == file.f_name.Split(' ')[0]))` is supposed to mean. As a matter of fact, that whole `if`...`else` seems to reference some kind of logic that really should be documented there with comments. It doesn't help that we don't have access to the code for `GenerateOrderNumberForRis`.
- There are two places where you do `documentOrderNumber + ".pdf"`.
- `Maindocument`, `Attdocument`, ... are compound words and thus should be PascalCase.